# How to get the width of the RelativeLayout which i have added to a TableRow in Android

Tags: android, gridview

Iam working on a code piece, which is generating the bookshelf view using the components TableLayout, HorizontalScrollView and RelativeLayout. I have a default cover page i have to place the title of the book on the coverpage and form the grid view (Book shelf).

Roughly the code looks like this

```
bitmapObj = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bookshelf_background_image);
tableLayoutObj = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tblLayout);
tableRowObj = new TableRow(this);
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++)
{ 
    horizontalScrollObj = new HorizontalScrollView(this
    for(int j = 0; j < numberOfColumns; j++) 
{
       relativeLayoutObj =(RelativeLayout) inflaterObj.inflate(R.layout.bookshelf_relative_layout, null);
       tableRowObj.addView(relativeLayoutObj);
    }   
}
```

What i wanted to know here is, i wanted to get the width of the relativelayout which iam adding to TableRob obj, so that i can define the paramater, how books i can place in a row.

Can any one help me please on this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of methods like:

1. view.getLeft();//returns the left position of the view relative to its parent
2. view.getRight();//returns the right position of the view relative to its parent similarly top and bottom
3. view.getWidth()
4. view.getHeight()

Answer (score 0):

I know its late, but I needed something like your question myself, and I came up with this solution. (it does NOT return 0, I checked)

```
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = YOURVIEW.getViewTreeObserver();
if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
  viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
      YOURVIEW.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
      viewWidth = YOURVIEW.getWidth();
      viewHeight = YOURVIEW.getHeight();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: yes i have tried, iam working on nexus device, the device width is 1080, but the relative layout width iam getting is 0 (zero)

Comment: have you set the weight to 0 in xml  ?

Comment: No. This is my xml file for relative layout
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_relative_layout_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#0000FF">

Comment: and it has 2 children. one is image view and the other is textview

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageviewid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/redbook" />

Comment: the text view is


 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewid"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="102dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imageviewid"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

Comment: try what I wrote in the edit, if that does not work, I will tell you another solution.

Comment: getLeft, getRight, getWidth and getMeasuredWidth, every thing is returning 0 :(

Comment: yah i have tried this as well, its returning the -1

Answer (score 0):

Probably at the time of execution of your code, your view hasn't been drawn yet, so its width and height are zero.

You can use the `view.post(Runnable)` and in the `Runnable` get their width and height ..

Comment: its returning the -1 in the public void run() method

Comment: are you sure it has been added to the view hierarchy ?

Comment: yah after calling the 'add' method only, iam calling to get the width of the View